# View in django not running

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where I'm trying to activate a user's account when they reset their password. I've created a custom view ActivateUserPasswordResetConfirmView that inherits from PasswordResetConfirmView and overrides the form_valid method to set user.is_active = True.

However, the form_valid method in my custom view does not seem to be called when a user resets their password. I've checked my URL configurations and they seem to be correct. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ActivateUserPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Add logging to see if this method is called
        logger.debug('ActivateUserPasswordResetConfirmView form_valid called')
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        logger.debug(f'User {user.username} activated')
        return response

@csrf_exempt
def typeform_webhook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        email = data['form_response']['answers'][0]['email']
        first_name = data['form_response']['answers'][1]['text']
        last_name = data['form_response']['answers'][2]['text']
        
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=email, email=email)
        if created:
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            # Generate a token for email confirmation
            token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
            uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))

            # Create a link for the user to set their password
            password_reset_link = request.build_absolute_uri(
                reverse('password_reset_confirm', kwargs={
                    'uidb64': uid, 'token': token
                })
            )

            # Send an email to the user with the password reset link
            send_mail(
                'Complete Your Registration',
                f'Please go to the following page and set a password: {password_reset_link}',
                'myemail@email.com',
                [email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'}, status=405)

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/template.html')
```

*myapp/urls.py:*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ActivateUserPasswordResetConfirmView

urlpatterns = [
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', ActivateUserPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    # other urls...
]
```

*project/urls.py:*

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # other urls...
]
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://ytqgjlt0m0z.typeform.com/to/Zmm6SiXz" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)){ js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also added logging in the form_valid method, but I don't see any log messages when testing the password reset flow, which suggests that the method is not being executed.

Any ideas on why the form_valid method is not being called or how I can debug this issue further?

Comment: If you're expecting that url to be called from a form submission, then show us the html template that contains the form.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have added more info into the post. The template contains a typeform that asks the user to type email and name. Then, once the form is completed a webhook is trigerred and send an email to the user to ask to set a password. once the password is reset the user should be activated. The URL in the email is a ngrok URL